# Is it possible two graphical interfaces at the same time in different tty?

Tags: tty, interface

For example using in tty7 the default desktop and in other tty using another graphical session with other user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly this is the default behavior when you are already logged in with one user and switch accounts.

When you login with the second user, usually tty8 is opened for that user.
You can then switch between the logins on tty7 and tty8 using `Strg-Alt-F7/F8`.